# Pandas plot values + headcount (=number of value)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

IHello guys, I actually couldn't find an answer to a my basic problem.
So I have 2 columns

```
     Age   Headcount
0    30         8
1    36         3
2    41         5
3    42         4
4    44         1
5    46         6
6    47         3
7    48         4
8    49         5
9    50         1
10   52         2
11   54         4
12   55         1
13   57         3
14   58         1
15   61         8
```

If i do

```
DataFrame.plot(x=DataFrame.Age, y=DataFrame.Headcount)
```

I Wil have

```
KeyError: '[8 3 5 4 1 6 3 4 5 1 2 4 1 3 1 8] not in index'
```

Even if I put my Headcount columns as an index, I will have similar error.

I could do a new pd.Series with eight 30, three 36 etc. and plot it, but it certainly possible to do it from my orignal DataFrame.

Thank's for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
DataFrame.plot(x='Age', y='Headcount')
```

**Explanation**

According to the [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) -

> x : label or position, default None
>
> y : label or position, default None
>
> Allows plotting of one column versus another

Specifying the label was enough, you don't need to pass the series explicitly!

Comment: @rSim if this is what you are looking for you would want to mark as answer so that others visiting this post will have clarity on the solution